# Getting rid of a circular dependency

Tags: java, design-patterns, circular-dependency

A `User` can belong to different `Group`s. And (by definition), a `Group` can have different members. Hence, the following classes:

```
class User {
    List<Group> groups;

    public User() {
        // initialize groups here
    }
}

class Group {
    List<User> members;

    public Group() {
        // initialize members here
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I create a `User`, it needs to create a `Group`, and when I create that `Group`, it needs to create the `User` again. How do I get rid of this infinite recursion?

---

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a set of `User`s, `Group`s and a relation that maps both of them stored in the database.

Whenever someone needs to use `User`, they create a `new User(<someId>)`. This gives them a new `User` object which is a proxy to the class (say `RealUser`) that actually fetches the data from the database. Internally, I keep a cache of `RealUser`s so that I don't fetch each `User` twice from the database. Similarly, a `Group` would be a proxy to the `RealGroup` class.

This is the reason *why* I'm creating `Group`s inside a `User`, and vice versa. They are all proxies to the real classes.

Comment: That's a problem-domain issue.  Why does a User need to create a Group *and* vice-versa?

Comment: Put differently, the problem is that they need to create each other, not that creating each other is problematic, which it is.

Comment: This structure is flawed from the beginning. It would mean that a user is made of a number of groups, each groups being made of a number of users (including the initial user and many others duplicated...). What you need is a set of users, a set of groups, a relation "is member of" and a relation "includes".

Comment: @YvesDaoust It is flawed indeed. Could you please elaborate on how I would represent the 1:N relations in Java (or just classes, for that matter)?

Comment: @JohnBupit: What would you do if you wanted to create a user in an existing group, without creating a duplicate group?

Comment: @immibis This made me think for a while. (I think I see the flaw now. Eventually, I'd have to get rid of keeping a `List` in one of the classes (one answer pointed this out, but it was deleted.)) I would call one of those: `user.joinGroup(group)` or `group.addMember(user)`. While implementing `user.joinGroup(group)`, I'd have to notify the `Group` that a member has been added - something like `group.addMember(this)` - this creates a similar infinite recursion problem.

Comment: @JohnBupit You can keep the lists in both classes, if there are no other problems with it. What you can't do is *create* groups when a user is created, *and* create users when a group is created. You could still have it so creating a `Group` creates all the `User`s in that group, then fills in their lists with references back to *that* `Group` (instead of creating a new one).

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I get it now. Something like the answer by @xmoex (that they deleted now, I think).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes... But where would these mappings be? Does it make sense to create a `GroupMembers` class for the mapping?

Comment: If the users and groups are sufficiently static, you can even think of using arrays and indexes into the arrays, but beware that any update must be reflected everywhere. I don't see a need for an extra class: users manage their groups and groups manage their users. Again, updates must be done consistently.

Comment: @JohnBupit are you trying to create your own ORM here? Hibernate can do this with a `@ManyToMany` annotation. Beyond that both groups and users can exists withouth each other by having an empty relationship. You can create both. When adding mutually you have to add in a check to if the current collection doesn't contain the new element and stop if it does.

Comment: @mpkorstanje In a way I am. I decided not to use Hibernate since I only have a couple of tables - it would be an overkill, wouldn't it. (I'm doing all this in an Android app)

Comment: @JohnBupit not if you're are already going through the trouble of making proxies, doing caching and all that. On top of that if you couple your entities like this you'll also have to setup lazy loading or you'll fetch all users and groups. So KISS and don't reinvent the wheel. ;)

Comment: This problem is at the root of "aggregation vs. composition". A user is not "composed-of" groups. Unless you are speaking of the Mafia, a group does not own a person. Therefore, creating users during the group creation process is wrong. You can later add a rules engine to implement restrictions (i.e. A member of group A cannot belong to group B or vice versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy option is to store the relationship between Users and Groups outside of those two classes.

For example, you could use a `java.util.Map` to map from users to groups, and vice-versa.

This is one possible representation:

```
Map<User,Set<Group>> mapUserToGroups = new HashMap<User,Set<Group>>();
Map<Group,Set<User>> mapGroupToUsers = new HashMap<Group,Set<User>>();
```

Or, if users and groups have unique IDs, the maps could refer instead to those IDs.

```
Map<String,Set<String>> mapUserIDToGroupIDs = new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();
Map<String,Set<String>> mapGroupIDToUserIDs = new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();
```

Comment: Or maybe just put this all into a database

Comment: @DavidGrinberg: Putting things in a database doesn't avoid needing to represent it in code at some point...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Right, but you no longer have the circular dependency issues. You can simply generate a list of all users in a group, or all groups a user is part of.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I do have them in a database. I'm trying to abstract them into the code so I don't have to fetch them from the database every time (see update).

Comment: Where would I have these sets? Would these sets be in a `GroupMembers` class? Would this be the _best_ option?

Comment: Yes, you could have a class that represents group membership, which provides a bidirectional mapping between users and groups. This is one of multiple reasonable options.

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern would be something like this (not threadsafe):

```
class User 
{
  private final static Map<String, User> USERS = new HashMap<>();

  public static User realize(String userId)
  {
    User user = USERS.get(userId);

    if (user == null) {
      user = new User(userId);
      USERS.put(userId, user);
    }

    return user;
  }

  private final Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();

  private User(String key)
  {
    USERS.put(key, this);

    Set<String> groupIds = getGroupsForUser(key);

    for (String id : groupIds) {
      groups.add(Group.realize(id));
    }

    // etc. initialization
  }
}

class Group
{
  private final static Map<String, Group> GROUPS = new HashMap<>();

  public static Group realize(String groupId)
  {
    Group group = GROUPS.get(groupId);

    return group == null ? new Group(groupId) : group;
  }

  private final Set<User> members = new HashSet<>();

  private Group(String key) 
  {
    GROUPS.put(key, this);
    Set<String> memberIds = getUsersForGroup(key);

    for (String id : memberIds) {
      members.add(User.realize(id));
    }

    // etc. initialization
  }
}
```

The issue here is that you are putting objects into the map before they are fully realized.  This might get ugly especially with multithreading.

A safer way is to just use the Ids as your links and realize them as needed using the same approach.  I would probably favor the latter approach since the former has the potential of pulling data and initializing objects for the entire directory on the first access.  Here's an example for the User class:

```
class User 
{
  private final static Map<String, User> USERS = new HashMap<>();

  public static User realize(String userId)
  {
    User user = USERS.get(userId);

    if (user == null) {
      user = new User(userId);
      USERS.put(userId, user);
    }

    return user;
  }

  private final Set<String> groupIds;

  private User(String key)
  {
    USERS.put(key, this);

    groupIds = getGroupsForUser(key);

    // etc. initialization
  }

  public Set<Group> getGroups()
  {
    Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();

    for (String id : groupIds) {
      groups.add(Group.realize(id));
    }

    return groups;
  }
}
```

I've use this type of design extensively over the last decade and it's fast, reliable and easy to maintain.